# JMeter JDBC Call specific parameter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I using JMeter Callable Statement to call procedure in database.
This procedure has 100+parameters, but only few of them required.

Is it possible call specific parameters, or i need call all of them?

Answer (score 0):

you call all of them by the right order.